# .save is not a function in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What is wrong with the way I am using Mongo? I am simply trying to update a record.

Here is my code:

```
async function updateReview (req, res) {
  const review = {
    ...req.body
  }

  const existingReview = await Review.findOne({
    userId: review.userId,
    launchId: review.launchId
  }).lean() 

  if (!existingReview) {
    return res.status(404).send()
  }
  existingReview.content = review.content
  existingReview.displayName = review.displayName
  existingReview.rating = review.rating

  await existingReview.save()
  return res.status(200)
}
```

So all I want to do is find the existing review and update some fields and save it. My code fails on the line:
`await existingReview.save()`.
The error says that `.save` is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.save()` function doesn't exist because you called `.lean()` which returns a normal JS object instead of a Mongoose object.

Instead of using `.save()` use one of the following options:

Example 1

```js
async function updateReview (req, res) {
  const review = {
    ...req.body
  }

  const existingReview = await Review.findOne({
    userId: review.userId,
    launchId: review.launchId
  }).lean() 

  if (!existingReview) {
    return res.status(404).send()
  }

  const { content, displayName, rating } = review;
  const { _id } = existingReview;

  await Review.updateOne({ _id }, { content, displayName, rating });

  return res.status(200)
}
```

Example 2

```js
async function updateReview (req, res) {
  const review = {
    ...req.body
  }

  const existingReview = await Review.findOne({
    userId: review.userId,
    launchId: review.launchId
  }).lean() 

  if (!existingReview) {
    return res.status(404).send()
  }

  const { content, displayName, rating } = review;
  const { _id } = existingReview;

  await Review.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { content, displayName, rating }).lean();

  return res.status(200)
}
```

Since you don't need the updated object, use `updateOne` instead of `findOneAndUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before.

```js
let view = await ViewCounter.findOne({post:pst}).lean();
```

It just happened because I was using `.lean()`. After removing it, it's worked.